# Throwing view not found but it does

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Register' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Account/Register.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Register.cshtml
```

Getting this error.

In my account controller, I have:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The view clearly exists:

[image]

I have tried both just in Account(where it should be..), just in shared, and in both as seen below.  Same error each time.  `Login` works just fine.  I have tried a clean build and get the same issue.

Comment: Please show us how you configure `.AddMvc()` in `ConfigureServices()`, and routing in `Configure()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you share your project on github?

Answer (score 0):

set routes.MapRoute on the project that you created